# how to display json data of wikipedia in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I want to display the text in the "extract:":......   of this JSON result form Wikipedia

```
{
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "from": "india",
                "to": "India"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "14533": {
                "pageid": 14533,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "India",
                "extract": "<p><b>India</b> (/\u02c8\u026andi\u0259/), officially the <b>Republic of India</b> (<i>Bharat Ganrajya</i>), is a country in South Asia. It is the seventh-largest country by area, the second-most populous country with over 1.2 billion people, and the most populous democracy in the world.</p>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This what I did but it failed:

```
url1 ="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=2&titles=india&format=json&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url1,function(result) {
    $.each(result.query, function(i,q) {
        $.each(q.pages, function(i,p) {
            $.each(p, function(i,j) {  
                content = '<p>' + j.extract  + '</p>';
                $(content).appendTo("#input");
            });
        });
    });
```

Please correct me

Comment: What error did it fail with?

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over

- `result.query`, which will callback with `normalized` and `pages` - unnecessary
- `pages` - which is OK
- `p`, which could callback with `pageid`, `ns`, `title` etc. which you don't want either.

Instead access those properties directly and use

```
var url1 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=2&titles=india&format=json&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url1, function(result){
    $.each(result.query.pages, function(i,p){
        var content = p.extract;
        $(content).appendTo("#input");
    });
});
```

Comment: You might [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) then :-)